# Table with information from database not showing up : System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, I made a connection to a database, created a table and successfully added a "View", so that I can go to www.mysite.com/TableView and everything shows up correctly. (Generated with a razor "strongly-type view" against my database model. I used the edmx wizard to create the database connection, and that generated a separate controller aswell.

I then wanted to show the table in my index.cshtml file. I copied the code generated in the TableView view, into the correct  in my index.cshtml, but it throws a System.NullReferenceException.

I cant quiet figure out why it wont work. It did work as a "standalone" view, but not when i paste it into another cshtml page?

I figured out it has something to do with the model, but why will it not work, when it worked in the other view.

Here is the code pasted into my index.cshtml from the working view :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class="page-full-width cf">
<div class="content-module">

    <div class="content-module-heading cf">

        <h3 class="fl">Full width page</h3>
        <span class="fr expand-collapse-text">Click to collapse</span>
        <span class="fr expand-collapse-text initial-expand">Click to expand</span>
    </div> <!-- end content-module-heading -->


    <div class="content-module-main">

   @model IEnumerable<WebEncode.Models.RunningJobsDb>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publish)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publish)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

    </div> <!-- end content-module-main -->

</div> <!-- end content-module -->
```

And here is my RunningJobsController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebEncode.Models;

  namespace WebEncode.Controllers
  {
public class RunningJobsController : Controller
{
    private WebEncodeDBEntities db = new WebEncodeDBEntities();

    //
    // GET: /RunningJobs/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.RunningJobsDb.ToList());
    }


    //
    // GET: /RunningJobs/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb = db.RunningJobsDb.Find(id);
        if (runningjobsdb == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(runningjobsdb);
    }

    //
    // GET: /RunningJobs/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /RunningJobs/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.RunningJobsDb.Add(runningjobsdb);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(runningjobsdb);
    }

    //
    // GET: /RunningJobs/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb = db.RunningJobsDb.Find(id);
        if (runningjobsdb == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(runningjobsdb);
    }

    //
    // POST: /RunningJobs/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(runningjobsdb).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(runningjobsdb);
    }

    //
    // GET: /RunningJobs/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb = db.RunningJobsDb.Find(id);
        if (runningjobsdb == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(runningjobsdb);
    }

    //
    // POST: /RunningJobs/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        RunningJobsDb runningjobsdb = db.RunningJobsDb.Find(id);
        db.RunningJobsDb.Remove(runningjobsdb);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    }
   }
```

And the model.

namespace WebEncode.Models
   {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class RunningJobsDb
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Publish { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public byte[] Remaining { get; set; }
}
}
```

I do know there are quiet a few questions about System.NullReference but I could not find any describing my kind of problem (may indicate I'm actually doing it in a stupid way)

Comment: Your `TableView` view was most likely is strongly typed to that model. Your layout page on the other hand is not strongly typed to the model, which would throw the null reference error.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I tried with RenderPartial aswell, but that throws a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What is the standard approach to achieve a simple task like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. And I feel rather stupid. I did not think about controllers and views in the right manner. After I read that the HomeController is responsible for the Views in /Home folder the issue presented itself.

I then moved the content from my RunningJobs controller, to HomeController. This way I could deliver the database content to my "Home/Index.cshtml" page with the ActionResult Index () function inside the HomeController.

The code itself was correct, the problem was me not realising the structure of MVC.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer as others may not see it down here.

Comment: Will do, but system wont let me do it until tomorrow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're not passing in the model when setting the ActionResult in your controller action. The code should look something like:

return View("ViewTable", < *instance of IEnumerable< RunningJobsDB > *>)

Cheers,

Marius

Answer (score 0):

You should delete first row in the table.Because your model is `IEnumerable<WebEncode.Models.RunningJobsDb>` not just  `RunningJobsDb` so you can't do this without foreach loop:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
```

here, model represents your `IEnumerable`, and it doesn't contain a `Title` property. You can use it with foreach,but you already doing it.just delete first line, it is redundant and cause the exception.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you say table, do you actually mean the "title" field / row in my database table? Or do you want me to remove the code you highlighted? Why would "title" field make problems? And not the Publish or status field?

Comment: Ahh, tried it now. Still the same exception. Updated Question with all the code.